# Why am I getting twice the records I expect?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following `Match` table:

```
+-----+---------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| id_ | tour_id | today_tours_ID_T | today_rounds_ID_R | today_players_ID1 | today_players_ID2 |
+-----+---------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|   1 |       0 |                1 |                 1 |                 1 |                 2 |
|   2 |       0 |                1 |                 1 |                 3 |                 4 |
|   3 |       1 |                1 |                 1 |                 1 |                 2 |
|   4 |       1 |                1 |                 1 |                 3 |                 4 |
+-----+---------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

And the following `games_table` table:

```
+-----+--------+--------+-------+-------+----------+--------+
| id_ | ID_T_G | ID_R_G | ID1_G | ID2_G | RESULT_G | DATE_G |
+-----+--------+--------+-------+-------+----------+--------+
|   1 |      1 |      1 |     1 |     2 | NULL     | NULL   |
|   2 |      1 |      1 |     3 |     4 | NULL     | NULL   |
+-----+--------+--------+-------+-------+----------+--------+
```

I want to get the records from `game` that match records in `match` where the relationship is defined by a composite key of the `ID` columns.

I've written the following query:

```
matches = dal.session.query(
    Match.id_,
    games_table.ID_T_G.label("ID_T_G"),
    games_table.ID_R_G.label("ID_R_G"),
    games_table.ID1_G.label("ID1_G"),
    games_table.ID2_G.label("ID2_G"),
    games_table.RESULT_G.label("RESULT_G"),
    games_table.DATE_G.label("DATE_G"),
)
games_matches_p1_winner = dal.session.query(
    games_table.ID_T_G.label("ID_T_G"),
    games_table.ID_R_G.label("ID_R_G"),
    games_table.ID1_G.label("ID1_G"),
    games_table.ID2_G.label("ID2_G"),
).subquery()
matches_p1_winner = (
    matches
    .select_from(Match)
    .join(
        games_matches_p1_winner,
        and_(
            Match.tour_id.__eq__(0),
            (
                Match.today_tours_ID_T
                .__eq__(games_matches_p1_winner.c.ID_T_G)
            ),
            (
                Match.today_rounds_ID_R
                .__eq__(games_matches_p1_winner.c.ID_R_G)
            ),
            (
                Match.today_players_ID1
                .__eq__(games_matches_p1_winner.c.ID1_G)
            ),
            (
                Match.today_players_ID2
                .__eq__(games_matches_p1_winner.c.ID2_G)
            ),
        )
    )
)
```

I was expecting it to return:

```
(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, None, None)
(2, 1, 1, 3, 4, None, None)
```

But I'm getting:

```
(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, None, None)
(1, 1, 1, 3, 4, None, None)
(2, 1, 1, 1, 2, None, None)
(2, 1, 1, 3, 4, None, None)
```

Why am I getting twice the records I expect?